# How to join table with comparation rule

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have `transaction data` and master `price`, I want calculate price of item by its weight, in table `price` we only store minimum of weight to avoid confusion between rules (conflict rule weight >0 and <5 | weight >3 and <5 for item with weight value 4). I have 2 tables like this

```
**Transactions table**

    id   item      weight
    --------------------
    1    Coffee    2
    2    Apple     7
    3    Computer  17

**Prices table**

    id  min_weight  price
    ----------------------
    1   0           200
    2   5           500
    3   10          1000
    4   20          2000
```

the result should be

```
id   item      weight   price
------------------------------
1    Coffee    2        200  (because 2 >= 0 and < 5) (in table price))
2    Apple     7        500  (because 7 >= 5 and < 10)
3    Computer  17       1000 (because 17 >= 10 and < 20)
```

and price rule weight >= 20 with price 2000 will be ignored. I try to simly join those tables

```
SELECT * FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN prices ON prices.weight >= transactions.weight
```

But i don't know how limit the weight in table price, I try to find out min weight and max weight (by next record value below the current record) but I don't know how to achieve this. Any idea? thanks.

**EDIT**
I just try this query to find out max weight of the records, I think this query will ignore gap id, order of weight or price, but still a little bit problem when find weight with same value, but consider another solution.

```
SELECT id, weight AS min_weight, 
(
    SELECT weight FROM prices AS next_prices
    WHERE weight = (SELECT MIN(weight) FROM prices AS all_prices WHERE weight > prices.weight)
) AS max_weight,
price 
FROM prices
```

Comment: Are you just looking for something as simple as `WHERE weight < 20`?

Comment: This is going to be tough to do in MySQL.  I would suggest storing the start and end of each price range in a separate row in the `Prices` table.  This would make your query much easier to handle.

Comment: @ObsidianAge We need to determine which price to join to.

Comment: We avoid conflict rule such as [min:0 - max:5] with [min:3 - max:6] and I have item with weight 4, then 2 prices will be applied to the item.

Answer (score 0):

This query will only work if the weight and price are BOTH in ascending order.

```
select id,item,weight,max(price) as price
   from (
        select t1.id, 
               t1.item,
               t1.weight,
                p.price 
         from t_transaction t1, t_price p
        where  t1.weight >= p.min_weight
        ) tab
group by id,
         item,
         weight;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to my mind is to add a max_weight to prices table. then you can use the following join:

```
select 
  t.id, 
  t.item, 
  t.weight, 
  p.price
from 
  transactions t 
  inner join prices p 
    on (t.weight > p.min_weight AND t.weight <= p.max_weight)
```

[See SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa30ff/3/0)